# Cannot extend my javascript object with Prototype

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
var Flippable = function( options, element ) {
    this.$el    = $( element );
    this._init( options );
};

Flippable.prototype     = {
    _init               : function( options ) {

        this.options        = $.extend( true, {}, $.Flips.defaults, options );
        this.$pages         = this.$el.children( 'div.f-page' );
        this.pagesCount     = this.$pages.length;
        this.History        = window.History;
        this.currentPage    = this.options.current;
        this._validateOpts();
        this._getWinSize();
        this._getState();
        this._layout();
        this._initTouchSwipe();
        this._loadEvents();
        this._goto();

    },
    foo: function(){alert("foo");}
}
```

But when I call Flipppable.foo(), I get undefined. Any ideas where my syntax is off?

Thanks!

Chris

** Update **

I"m creating a plugin like so:

```
$.fn.flippable = function( method ) {

// Method calling logic
if ( Flippable[method] ) {
  return Flippable[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
} else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
  return Flippable._init.apply( this, arguments );
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.flippable' );
    }

};

It borks on line:

```
return Flippable._init.apply( this, arguments );
```

_init is undefined.

Comment: Have you created an object with `new Flippable()`? PS: it's common to modify `prototype`, not completely override.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prototype functions are accessible only through the object of the class. And not the class itself.
This would work.

```
var oFlip = new Flippable();
oFlip.foo();
```

Comment: They are also accessible through the prototype object of Flippable since this is where they are declared.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to call foo using .apply you will have to do this.

```
Flippable.prototype.foo.apply( this, arguments );
```

The object which has a foo property is prototype on Flippable and not Flippable itself.